# Haskell Bounded DataTypes, constructed from value-bounds

Tags: haskell, reflection

I have the following type in Haskell, to represent values between 0&23.  There's more for handling the arithmetic; elided here for space.

```
newtype N24 = N_24 Word16
  deriving (Enum, Eq, Integral, NFData, Ord, Real, Show)

toN24 ∷ (Integral α, Num α) ⇒ α → N24
toN24 n@(toInteger → n') | n' < toInteger (minBound @N24) = throw Underflow
                         | n' > toInteger (maxBound @N24) = throw Overflow
                         | otherwise                     = N_24 (fromIntegral n)

instance Bounded N24 where
  minBound = N_24 0
  maxBound = N_24 23
```

Now, I want to build a similar type for N60.  And another for N12.

My question is, can I design a higher-order type(?), e.g., 'BoundedN' such that I could declare

n60 :: BoundedN 60
  n12 :: BoundedN 12

that implemented the above, but without having to copy-and-paste the entire definition.  I've tried to use Reflection, but honestly, I'm not understanding it and just bouncing on the keys trying to find stuff that works isn't getting me anywhere.  I could do it with TemplateHaskell, but I consider that a last resort (at best, it will be relatively hard to read, I fear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to design such a type; indeed, it has already been done! The [`finite-typelits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/finite-typelits) library defines a type `Finite n`, which can only be inhabited by the values from `0` to `n-1`. For instance, `Finite 5` is inhabited by the numbers 0–4, but does not permit any other value. This functionality relies on the `DataKinds` extension, which allows the use of integers (amongst other things) at the type level. Take a look at the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/finite-typelits-0.1.4.2/docs/src/Data.Finite.Internal.html) of the library if you’re interested in seeing how this works; the most important part is:

```hs
-- | Finite number type. @'Finite' n@ is inhabited by exactly @n@ values. Invariants:
--
-- prop> getFinite x < natVal x
-- prop> getFinite x >= 0
newtype Finite (n :: Nat) = Finite Integer
                          deriving (Eq, Ord, Generic)

-- | Convert an 'Integer' into a 'Finite', throwing an error if the input is out of bounds.
finite :: KnownNat n => Integer -> Finite n
finite x = result
    where
        result = if x < natVal result && x >= 0
            then Finite x
            else error $ "finite: Integer " ++ show x ++ " is not representable in Finite " ++ show (natVal result)

-- | Convert a 'Finite' into the corresponding 'Integer'.
getFinite :: Finite n -> Integer
getFinite (Finite x) = x
```

Comment: Oh, fab.  Thank you @bradrn!  That'll be just what I need.

Comment: You’re welcome @user3416536! I’ve used this library before — it is indeed very useful for when you need it!